# Right click on desktop not opening

Tags: windows-10

I have just upgraded to `windows 10` but after upgrading `RIGHT click` *(on desk top the popup menu used to refresh)* just doesn't open. It opens up after 10-15 minutes. Till then it just loads, loads and loads. So basically I'm not able to refresh in windows 10. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot you PC? Usually but not always, this is a symptom of too many works that your PC's CPU are working on. Just reboot your laptop and see if everything is going back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can always refresh with F5.

As for the cause of the problem, usually this is caused by some program(s) adding their functionality into the "right click menu". See for example http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/slow-right-click-context-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can use your keyboard as mouse ...Here is an article to help you with: [How to use Keyboard as mouse](http://www.techtechnik.com/2014/05/turn-your-android-phone-into-wireless-computer-mouse.html)

Comment: Please provide some context from that link.

Comment: Links die all the time and, if the link in your answer dies, there'll be nothing left. Please edit your answer so it contains all the necessary information, citing the article you link as a source and a place to go for further reading.